# Make old git branches invisible without making them unreachable?

Tags: git, branch, gitk

Is there a way to make a git branch cease to show up when you type "git branch", but still remain reachable in the history, i.e. via gitk?  I have many old branches that I want to get out of my sight, but I see no reason to delete history even of development dead-ends in a world with terabyte hard disks.

Tags might be close to what I'm looking for, but I don't want to have to name my dead ends beyond their commit message.  Furthermore, I want reserve tags for especially good points in the mainline development history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push the old branches to a remote repository on one of the many free Git hosting sites.

Comment: ...or, more efficiently and conveniently, to a locally cloned repository.  On linux, hard links will be used automatically to share storage between the clone and the original.

Answer (score 6):

You can make up your own namespace inside `refs/`, such as `refs/historic/foo`, by manually using the `update-ref` command (and then deleting the branch).

Some caveats of this approach:

- They do not show up in `git branch`, but they do show up in `git log --decorate` and in `gitk` without any extra options, and you may use `git show-ref` to list all refs.
- They are not automatically fetched, so you if you want them transported you will have to use `ls-remote` and `fetch` them by hand.

However, it seems like a nice way to archive a branch, since it pops up when browsing history, can be explicitly listed, and does not clutter the branch or tag namespace.

Answer (score -3):

git revision IDs are (nearly) unique.  If you want the old branches to remain reachable, just don't garbage collect them; you can always bring them back by directly checking out their revision ID.  This will require tweaking the `.git/config` of your repository to avoid having a `git gc` clear out the revisions no longer reachable directly from the HEAD of any branch.

Comment: Disabling auto gc is a poor choice: an actively developed repository will consume a lot more space.